# C# Thead-Safe collection in Object

Tags: c#, thread-safety

**This is just example code to illustrate my question.**

Assume I have the following class:

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


namespace BoxesA4
{
class Box
{
    public double length { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }

ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> boxItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();


    public Box(double length,double width,double height)
    {
        this.length=length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }

    public double volume()
    {
        return this.length * this.width * this.height;
    }

    public void add(int index,string item)
    {
        boxItems.TryAdd(index, item);

    }



    }
}
```

Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Box createBox = new Box(10,10,5,5);
       createBox.add(0,"hammer");
       createBox.add(1,"saw");

    }
```

In my main method I am calling createBox.add(); and passing the necessary arguments. Do I have to worry about thread-safety when it comes to calling my add method? **I don't want to make the Box class static**. If thread-safety is an issue how would I go about fixing my code?

Comment: How exactly it can be an issue, if you are creating a local object?

Comment: As an aside, it looks like `volume` should be a property, and I'd strongly encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @Nikita Brizhak- You never know. I was just wondering and decided to ask. I didn't want to go along with my project only to find that it isn't thread-safe to begin with.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I know. I just quickly whipped together this class to ask the question.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: It's worth spending an extra couple of minutes to make it more conventional code in future. Anything that distracts those who are trying to answer is a bad thing.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield, well it's not like you _can't_ know. You _could_ do some reading on threading first, and on how it can affect your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the behaviour of [`ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291.aspx) meets your requirements, you're fine. You'd be in an even better position if you made the `boxItems` field read-only.

It's worth reading the docs in detail when you use the concurrent collections, to see exactly what can happen. For example, you *may* want `AddOrUpdate` instead of `TryAdd` - what you do *want* to happen if the key already exists in the dictionary?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: Right - it's not clear what you mean by "issue a message" but you'll need to use the result of `TryAdd`...

Comment: Is it possible to use the containskey method and check it see if the key exists and if so, inform the user?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield you can use ContainsKey method. See the link i have given  in my answer to get detailed description. By the way you can also get the return of tryadd to see if it was already present or newly added. Again see the details in link

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: No, you should use `TryAdd` - because otherwise the key might be absent when you check for it, but then get added just before you insert. That's why `TryAdd` returns whether or not it actually added the value - it's atomic.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread safety is not an issue in your case`. your box.add method is effectively adding to [Concurrent dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which is thread safe. So you need not worry about thread safety.